# Linking tables on date basis

Tags: sql-server

I am having two tables as below
Child_Attendance
childid     updatedon     presentdays
1           31/01/2018    20
1           28/02/2018    15
1           31/03/2018    18
1           30/04/2018    24
1           31/05/2018    17
1           30/06/2018    19
2           31/03/2018    25
2           30/04/2018    28
2           31/05/2018    22
2           30/06/2018    23

And the Second table as

childid     class           admissiondate
1           creches         15/06/2017
1           balwari         01/02/2018
2           creches         01/01/2017
2           balwari         01/01/2018
2           Bridge Course   01/04/2018

Now, I need a query to return childid,updatedon,presentdays,class.

I am new to sql and don't have any idea how to do it. 
I have tried

```
SELECT t1.childid,t1.updatedon,t1.presentdays,t2.class
   FROM child_attendance t1 LEFT JOIN class_allocation t2
   ON t1.childid = t2.childid
   AND t1.updatedon >= t2.admissiondate
```

My output should be like this

[image: Output]

You can see the child 1 was admitted in creche on dated 15/06/2017 and balwari on dated 01/02/2018. This means he was in creche from 15/06/2018 till 01/02/2018.

Comment: How did your query fail to satisfy your requirement?

Comment: can you share the expected output?

Comment: @Santosh: Please use TEXT table layouts not images! so other could help you faster.

Comment: I have edited and converted pics table in text table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query could get what you want:

```
SELECT t1.childid, t1.updatedon, t1.presentdays,
    class=(SELECT TOP (1) class
            FROM Class_Allocation
            WHERE childid=t1.childid
            AND t1.updatedon>=admissiondate
            ORDER BY admissiondate DESC)
   FROM Child_Attendance t1
```